# php bin/console me da error

Tags: symfony3

Mi computadora es Windows 8 y hace poco comensé a trabajar con Symphony el problema es que cuando pongo el comando de **php bin/console** en mi "consola" esta me da error(**"php"no se reconoce como un comando interno o extreno, programa o archivo de lotes ejecutables.**)
Alguien podria decirme que puedo hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso significa que no tienes php ejecutándose en tu equipo y es algo que no depende del SO. ¿Tienes un servidor arrancado? Lo más cómodo en Windows en que instales xampp

Perdona mi atrevimiento pero por la pregunta da la impresión que no tienes mucha practica en entornos de trabajo con PHP y si ese es el caso, empezar a trabajar con symfony creo que te va a resultar extremadamente difícil ya que de por si la curva de aprendizaje es bastante dura y sin unos conocimientos sólidos de php y bases de datos te va a resultar muy complicado.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo pero si esto es lo que nos piden q aprendamos en las clases, hay que aprender aunque sea el mínimo

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tengas PHP dentro de las variables de entorno del Windows, busca en la variable path y revisa que se encuentre la ruta del ejecutable de php. La variable path permite que la consola de comandos reconozca programas a ejecutar.